# delete rows based on the source

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 sets of data coming from 2 tables.

```
Table 1: id, type, source
Table 2: id, type, source
```

If there is a matching record in `table1` and `table2` by `id` and `type` then `table2` rows takes priority and rows coming from `table1` needs to be deleted.

is there a quick way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete them in the table, then you can use a `join`:

```
delete t1
    from table1 t1
    where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.type = t2.type)
```

If you just want a query that prioritizes the results, so they come from table2 first, then:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
union all
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.type = t2.type)
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way will be delete based on join:

```
DELETE T1
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.TYPE = T2.TYPE
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using brute force

```
;WITH 
    CTE_TBL2 AS (SELECT * FROM final WHERE source = 't1')
,   CTE_TBL1 AS (SELECT * FROM final WHERE source = 't2')
,   CTE_DEL AS
        (
            SELECT
                    *
            FROM    CTE_TBL1
            WHERE   EXISTS  (   SELECT  1 
                                FROM    CTE_TBL2 
                                WHERE   CTE_TBL1.id     = CTE_TBL2.id 
                                AND     CTE_TBL1.type   = CTE_TBL2.type
                            )
        )
DELETE  final
FROM    final F
INNER JOIN CTE_DEL
ON      F.id        = CTE_DEL.id
AND     F.type      = CTE_DEL.type
AND     F.source    = CTE_DEL.source
```

Comment: The stated question is two tables (not one)